# Is there a way to remove the titlebar from a JavaFX UI that is using StageStyle.UTILITY

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm creating a simple overlay in Java and as such I'd like a single AnchorPane that doesn't have any title bar, doesn't show an icon in the taskbar, StatgeStyle.UTILITY achieves one of these, the no icon in the taskbar, however, it doesn't achieve the no title bar, whereas StageStyle.UNDECORATED achieves the no title bar but it shows up as an icon in the taskbar. So what I want is to somehow remove the titlebar from a StageStyle.UTILITY or remove an icon showing up in the taskbar when using StageStyle.UNDECORATED, I think the StageStyle.UTILITY problem is easier to solve.

I remember reading about wrapping the JavaFX anchor inside of a JPanel but I can't remember the link of it and I can't seem to find it by searching anymore, I have only worked with JavaFX UI's as such I don't know how I would have to start with a JPanel.

I've also tried some more solutions, paraphrasing:
I had to set the ownership of the stage to a stage that had the other style and it should work (it didn't)

```
 primaryStage.setStyle(StageStyle.UTIILITY)
```

The expected result is a StageStyle.UTILITY without a titlebar

OR

A StageStyle.UNDECORATED without the icon showing up in the taskbar.

Comment: Would using a popup be an option?

Comment: Maybe this can help you fix your problem http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#popover ?